# Check if a vertex in a graph belongs to loop

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I have a undirected graph(might have multiple edges) and I need to check if a given vertex belongs to some loop or not in `O(|V|)`. Note that the graph can be dense.

Comment: Well if I had to just detect a cycle, I could apply DFS and keep count of edges till (n-1) after which I'll be sure that there is a cycle. So I solve this in O(n). But whether or not a vertex belongs to a cycle in a graph with multiple edges is tougher.

Comment: Is the graph known to be connected?

Comment: @greybeard - I made some changes in my answer which should work even for a disconnected graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vertex will belong to a loop if you can walk out of it and come back later through other vertices.

An algorithm can be as following:

1. Add current vertex V<sub>0</sub> to list of visited vertices, V.
2. While sizeof(V) < N we will list V<sub>1</sub>, ..., V<sub>k</sub> to which you can go from V<sub>0</sub>
3. Repeat step 2 until you find V<sub>0</sub> on the way - which means it's in a loop - or until sizeof(V) = N or no new vertex can be added to V (graph may be disconnected).  **Note:** Repeating step 2 means we find list of vertices to which we can go from the set of last added (V<sub>1</sub>, ..., V<sub>k</sub>).

With this algorithm I see that each vertex is checked only once, so it's O(|V|).

Comment: This seems to assume the graph to be connected _and_ the degree to be limited.

Comment: @greybeard I see.  So if the graph is disconnected, we don't know when to exit the loop.  I will think some more.  Thanks.

Comment: @greybeard - We will stop when we cannot any more vertex.

Comment: @greybeard - I've corrected my answer to exit also when we cannot add a new vertex to the set.

Comment: so when sizeof(V)=N, you output that it is there in the cycle.

Comment: @sudeepdino008 if we reached the point where sizeof(V) = N, or no new vertex can be added, but we didn't meet V0 on the way, that means it's not in a loop at all.

Comment: @sudeepdino008 - you can check if now the answer is good for you.

Comment: In step 2, you need check all neighbors of vertex V0, so the time complexity is the sum of degree of each vertex, that is O(E). Generally, the running time of BFS is O(V+E). O(V+E) is O(V) only if E is proportional with V.

Comment: @notbad Thanks a lot for your comment. Probably there should be a way to store directed edges, so that we don't have to scan all of them, but use some quick search among them. Our objective at each step is to search for outgoing links with V0 only.

Comment: @TimothyHa Yeah, hope so:)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep removing leaf (with only 1 non-mutiple edge) in the graph. If the v is not in a cycle, it must be moved. Also, v can't be removed when it contains in some cycle, since any vertex on the cycle won't become a leaf. You need remove |V| vertices at most, also, you need consider only one edge because you are removing a leaf at each step. So it is  O(V) approach.

Comment: I suppose you missed the 'if I had to just detect a cycle' portion. Cycle detection can be done in O(n) even for multiple edges from the approach you mentioned. But finding whether a given vertex belongs to some cycle is tougher.

Comment: @sudeepdino008 I have updated my answer. Hope it help.

Comment: Hmmm...rather clean. :) Can this algorithm be extended to directed graphs? How will you a leaf in that case?

Comment: I am not sure if it can be solved in O(V) in directed graph. At least, you can use the strongly connected component algorithm. It needs BFS in the origin graph and the complementary graph. I don't  know whether there is any algorithms independent with edges.

Comment: Sorry, it should be DFS to find strongly connected component:)

Answer (score 0):

A vertex, `v` belongs to a cycle iff a `DFS` rooted at this vertex contains a back-edge adjacent to `v`. It is easy to see that this condition is sufficient. To show that it is necessary, consider a cycle that `v` belongs to. Let its neighbours in this cycle be `x` and `y`. Since `x`, `y` and `v`, lie in a cycle, there is a path from `v` to `y` going through `x` and vice versa. Hence, `x` and `y` lie in the same subtree of the `DFS`. Thus, at least one of the edges, `xv` and `yv`, cannot be a tree-edge. In other words, at least one of those two edges is a backedge.

Comment: While this is true, DFS takes O(|V|+|E|) time which for dense graph is quadratic in number of vertices. I was looking to obtain it independent of number of edges.